# convert from one memory format to another and find the difference between them

Tags: shell

Using shell scripting, how can I convert from one memory format to another and find the difference between them?

I want to compare `current rate` and `previous memory rate` (Where we need to compare decimal value with integer).

If it is positive it should display growth,
If its negative it should display no growth,
If it is 0 it should display constant.

For example

```
Name      current previous  
           rate   rate
Raju       6.7M  6.9M     
sita       52K   52K      
ravi       76K   76K       
seetha     52K   52K      
geetha     153M  56K      
ritta      13M   7.8G
```

This is just a sample output--I want output like this!

```
Name      current previous  difference comment
           rate   rate
Raju       6.7M  6.9M     -0.2        No growth
sita       52K   52K       0          constant
ravi       76K   76K       0          constant
seetha     52K   52K       0          constant
geetha     153M  56K       97         growth
ritta      13M   7.8G      5.2        growth
```

Comment: for programming questions you might want to ask your question on [so]. however keep in mind, that none of the StackExchange sites are there to do your homework: what have you tried to solve the problem? and please don't add any "urgent" boilerplates.

Comment: Please comment where is mistake : 153M - 56K != 97 but == 152944000 Or you need not count multiplay suffixes ?